# Disable date in mat datepicker conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material datepicker in an angular 7 project. I want to make the datepicker readonly on some condition. eg. if the date is more than the current date I want to make the datepicker readonly and not let the user to change the date.

I tried this.disableDate = true; and then tried the [readonly] property and also tried the disabled property but it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you applied the disabled property but it should work if you apply it on the input. mat-datepicker uses `matInput` which has `disabled` property. You can bind the property with your condition. The datepicker icon and the input field is disabled once the condition meets on the input.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [disabled]="true">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Here is my code and it does not work:                                                                  
   <mat-form-field>
                      <input color="primary" readonly [min]="minDate" [disabled]="true" [(ngModel)]="committeeModel.endDate" matInput
                        [matDatepicker]="endDate" (ngModelChange)="updateEndDate($event)">
                      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                      <mat-datepicker #endDate disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>

Answer (score -1):

DatePiecker has **max** property you can set it to whatever value you want

Component

```
maxDate = new Date();
```

**Template.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi Mamta, I dont want to disable future dates. I dont want the user to change the date on a specific condition so I want to disable the calender on a specific condition.

Comment: In this case if you already have that condition you can use [disable]="your condition" or if you want the case when user select a date that time you want to do some action than you can use dateChange property of date picker

Comment: @YogeshMali i have updated stackblitz code for disable date. Please check

Comment: Thanks Mamta, can you please share the code, I dont see it. Also what I am looking for is to disable the option to select the date.